# how can i find the location next to a randomly generated location

Tags: python

i am working on a maze generator using the random module mainly and generating tiles on a grid.
right now i am trying to prevent 2 by 2s as i think it is a waste of space however if i try to calculate the location next to the random tile i have created i get a 'list index out of range' error

```
    import random

    end = 90
    i = 0
    while i < end:
        RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
        RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
        Extra1 = RandomRow + 1
        Extra2 = RandomRow - 1
        Extra3 = RandomColumn + 1
        Extra4 = RandomColumn - 1

        if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
            if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow + 1]:
                TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
                Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
        else:
            end += 1 
        i += 1
```

the 'RandomRow + 1' was a test as well as the extra1,2,3 and 4 but none of them have worked

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode([710, 710])  
Done = False                                  
MazeSize = 10

TileWidth = 60
TileMargin = 10

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

class MapTile(object):                       
    def __init__(self, Name, Column, Row):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Column = Column
        self.Row = Row


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, Column, Row):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Column = Column
        self.Row = Row

        Maze.update()
        

class Maze(object):              #The main class; where the action happens
    global MapSize

    Grid = [[None for col in range(11)] for row in range(11)]

# Creating grid

    for Row in range(MazeSize):     
        Grid.append([])
        for Column in range(MazeSize):
            Grid[Row].append([])          
            
#making walls

    end = 9
    i = 0
    while i < end:
        RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
        RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
        Extra1 = RandomRow + 1
        Extra2 = RandomRow - 1
        Extra3 = RandomColumn + 1
        Extra4 = RandomColumn - 1

        if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
            if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow + 1]:
                TempTile = 'x'
                Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow] = (TempTile)
        else:
            end += 1 
        i += 1
            
#making the whole grid flat land
            
    for Row in range(MazeSize):     
        for Column in range(MazeSize):
            TempTile = MapTile('path', Column, Row)
            Grid[Column][Row] = (TempTile)

Maze = Maze()
run = True
while run:     

    for event in pygame.event.get():         
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False       

    Screen.fill(BLACK)

    for Row in range(MazeSize):           
        for Column in range(MazeSize):
            for i in range(1):
                Color = WHITE
                if len(Maze.Grid[Column][Row]) == 2:
                    Color = RED
                if len(Maze.Grid[Column][Row]) >= 3:
                    Color = BLUE
                    

            pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TileMargin + TileWidth) * Column + TileMargin,
                                             (TileMargin + TileWidth) * Row + TileMargin,
                                             TileWidth,
                                             TileWidth])

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

this is the whole code (the problem is at the bottom) when i started to change the grid i had to change a couple of things to make it work however now i am stuck at this one error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\faith\OneDrive\Desktop\websites\maze generator.py", line 88, in 
if len(Maze.Grid[Column][Row]) == 2:
TypeError: object of type 'MapTile' has no len()

Comment: Can you give the value of `MazeSize` and `Grid` ? Can you give the full traceback ?

Comment: MazeSize = 10 and Grid is an empty list that I am placing tiles in

Answer (score 0):

You get a `IndexError: list index out of range` if you try to evaluate `Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]` on an empty list.

You can initiate Grid with an 10x10 array filled with `None` with:

```
Grid = [[None for col in range(10)] for row in range(10)]
```

This will give you *a* result (not sure it will be what you want):

```
import random

MazeSize = 10
Grid = [[None for col in range(11)] for row in range(11)]

end = 90
i = 0
while i < end:
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow + 1]:
            TempTile = 'x'
            Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow] = TempTile
    else:
        end += 1 
    i += 1
    
for i in Grid:
  print(i)
```

Comment: @FaithlessS is my answer helpful ?

Comment: i tried the code but now i am getting a new error: Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @FaithlessS That's why you need to use `Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow] = TempTile`

Comment: this change has caused multiple other errors in the program i am still trying to modify it but it seems promising i will let you know if it works